# How would I prove the dual of $L^1$ Is isomorphic to $L^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've really hit a brick wall trying to prove the dual of $L^1$ Is isomorphic (as a normed space) to $L^\infty$ ?

Comment: There is a natural injective morphism $\psi: L^\infty \to (L^{1})^*$ defined by  

$$\psi(f)(g) = \int f(x)g(x) dx$$

The hard part is the surjectivity, and this is often proved with the help of the Radon-Nykodim.

Comment: That should be Nikodym, in case you're looking it up.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 6):

Let's say this is over a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X,\Sigma,m)$.
A bounded linear functional $\varphi$ on $L^1$ defines a real-valued function $\mu$ on sets of finite $m$-measure by $\mu(E) = \varphi(I_E)$, where $I_E$ is the indicator function of $E$.

Temporarily restrict to 
subsets of a set $A$ of finite $m$-measure.  It is easy to show that this restriction of $\mu$ is a (signed) measure absolutely continuous with respect to $m$, and therefore by Radon-Nikodym is given by integration with an $L^1$ function $g_A$, i.e.

$$ \varphi(I_E) = \int_E g_A \; dm \ \text{for}\ E \in \Sigma \ \text{with}\ E \subseteq A$$

Then for any $f \in L^1(m)$ that is $0$ outside $A$, you can show
$ \varphi(f) = \int_A g_A f \; dm$.

Moreover, it's easy to show $|g_A(x)| \le \|\varphi\|$ for $m$-almost every $x \in A$.  Next, show that these are consistent: $g_A = g_B$ $m$-almost everywhere in $A \cap B$.  Using the fact that $m$ is $\sigma$-finite, we can take a sequence $A_n$ and get a single $g \in L^\infty(m)$ such that $g = g_{A_n}$ on $A_n$, and $\varphi(f) = \int g f \; dm$ for all $f \in L^1(m)$.

EDIT:
You do need the $\sigma$-finiteness condition.  Consider $X = [0,1]$ with the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ consisting of subsets of $X$ that are either countable or co-countable (i.e. their complement is countable), and $m$ counting measure.  Thus $L^1(m)$ consists of
functions $f$ such that $f(x) = 0$ outside some countable set and
$\sum_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| < \infty$.  Consider the linear functional

$$ \varphi(f) = \sum_{x \in [0,1/2]} f(x) $$

which is easily seen to have norm $1$.  If $\varphi(f) = \int g f \; dm$, we would need $g(x) = 1$ for $x \in [0,1/2]$ and $0$ for $x \in (1/2, 1]$, but this is not a measurable function so it's not in $L^\infty$.

Hmm.  That shows that this particular mapping does not take $L^\infty(m)$ onto $(L^1(m))^*$.  I don't know whether there could be some other isomorphism in this case.

EDIT: More generally, in this example for any bounded function $h$ on $[0,1]$ (no measurability required!) you have a unique bounded linear functional

$$ \phi_h(f) = \sum_x h(x) f(x) $$

The cardinality of these is $c^c$.  On the other hand, each member of $L^\infty(m)$ has a constant value outside of some countable set, so the cardinality of $L^\infty(m)$ is $c$.  So $(L^1(m))^*$ is much too big to be isomorphic to $L^\infty(m)$ in this case.